# Remove scratches from color scanned image with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Could you please guide me on how I can remove these line from this image?

[image: scratched image]

The attached color image is scratched by red, blue, and black pen. Without converting this image to gray scale, I tried this code:

```
w=ones(13)/(13*13);
img2(:,:,3)= imfilter(imgb,w);
figure,imshow(img2)
```

I tried this code for each color layer, to remove the red color in the red layer, the blue color in blue layer, and so on.

Comment: There is no image attached. You can paste the link to a hosting website and someone will add the image to your post. Thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11: Often when this occurs it seems the user has tried to upload an image but doesn't have the reputation to actually add it. In this case SO just leaves a broken link that can be seen if one edits the question. Users with sufficient privileges can insert the image properly. Or maybe the OP broke the link themselves.